# Can I disable tabs in the Finder?

Tags: finder, macos, tabs

I frequently use command-click in the titlebar to open the parent folder of a folder in the Finder.  In Mavericks, instead of opening a new window with the same view style, it opens a new tab in "column" view.

Is there any way to disable Finder tabs?  I don't want them, ever, and especially not when command-clicking a titlebar.

Answer (score 9):

Finder → Preferences → General → uncheck Open folders in tabs instead of new windows

Comment: This does NOT work under High Sierra, precisely macOS 10.13.2 (17C88), on a new MacBook Pro. Even editing the com.apple.finder.plist for the "obvious" instances of the string "tab" does not seem to work. Sigh. I want to see the contents of multiple finder windows -at the same time- which is something finder with tabs enabled is preventing.