# I can't disable tabs in finder

Tags: macos, finder, tabs

I have been having this problem for a few months now. Normally, it didn't show tabs when only one tab was open. (Just like how it is in Safari) But one day, tabs appeared on Finder and they don't go away.

[image: My screenshot]

I want the + and applications bar back from under the configurable icon control area at the top of the finder window shown above.

I tried turning on and off every feature related to tabs in Preference panel. I included a screenshot of how it looks and another screenshot from my friend's computer that shows how I want it to be.

[image: How it should look]

Is this a setting it preference I can change back?

Comment: Does Cmd/Shift/T not work? https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAP3t.png

Comment: Also curious if you have open new windows as tabs enabled - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/111058/5472 you do a [better job of describing this than over there.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/345554/5472)

Comment: I had no idea Cmd/Shift/T was a thing! It worked. How does the menu you are showing a screenshot is opened? I right-clicked everywhere but it doesn't show that many options.

Comment: It's in the main View menu at the top.